# Why Stack, Queue and LinkedList considered as Linear Data Structure?

Tags: data-structures

I read few books, but still didn't understand why its considered as linear. Not sure because of appearance or sequential access or something else. If possible please explain in some logical terms.

Comment: Linked lists and stacks can all be implemented by very similar data structures, and they are linear.  Not sure what you don't understand here.

Answer (score 4):

Data structures fall into two categories: Linear and Non-Linear. A data structure is said to be linear if the elements form a sequence, for example Array, Linked list, queue etc. Elements in a nonlinear data structure do not form a sequence, for example Tree, Hash tree, Binary tree, etc.

There are two ways of representing linear data structures in memory. One way is to have the linear relationship between the elements by means of sequential memory locations. Such linear structures are called arrays. The other way is to have the linear relationship between the elements represented by means of links. Such linear data structures are called linked list.

Comment: Thanks to provide the meaningful and logical answer. Please correct me if i understand wrong. Form a sequence can be a Tree also, if tree has only left child node.e.g Left skew tree. If this is a scenario can assume its come under Linear?

Comment: This link can be helpful:
https://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/DataStructures/Lessons/NonlinearDS/index.html

Their differences are related to the type of memory representation.

Comment: Thanks. Found one more answer over forum that's really helped. "A tree is a nonlinear data structure, compared to arrays, linked lists, stacks and queues which are linear data structures. But particular case of skewed-ness it becomes linear. That deviation from it's non-linearity gives it no advantage compared to linear structures like list." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861914/nature-of-tree-data-structure

Answer (score 0):

That is so because they follow a linear - fashion, they move from one block to another step - by - step.

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists, Stack, Queues are linear because they have connected in a manner that they can have only one descendant at any node. Unlike trees and graphs which can have one or more child or nodes connected to a given node.

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine nature .

When the events occur one after the other - you go for linear  (time events , age , weather etc ) .

When the events branch out - you go for non linear (for example food-chain , biological nomenclature , classification of living beings into kingdoms , family etc )

Answer (score 0):

Linked list :-
Linked list is a collection of nodes .
It has a end to end connection.one node is hold the address of  another node or next node i.e. nodes are dependent on each other. They are connected in a linear manner.hence linked list is called as a linear data structure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Linear data structures:

the elements (objects) are sequential and ordered in a way so that:

there is only one first element and has only one next element,

there is only one last element and has only one previous element, while

all other elements have a next and a previous element

https://codeandwork.github.io/courses/java/linearDataStructures.html

non-linear data structures are those that are not linear!